# cloud composer pythonoperator to call an email function fails with missing positional argument

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a python operator to call a function to send e-mail but I am getting an error

> missing 1 required positional argument: `contextDict`

```
def send_email(contextDict, **kwargs):
        """Send custom email alerts."""

        # email title.
        title = "THIS IS A TEST"+file_name+" Failed"

        # email contents
        body = """
        Hi Everyone, <br>
        <br>
        This is a test pls ignore .<br>
        <br>
        """
        send_email('email@domain.com', title, body)
```

and I am calling it with:

```
PythonOperator(task_id='fail_task',
                         python_callable=notify_email,
                         provide_context = True,
                         dag=dag)
```

I  am just trying to send an e-mail based on a condition upstream (I am not looking for  e-mail on task failure) by using branching

I believe I should pass `op_args` to the function but I am not sure what to pass to context dictionary as it already has all the macros, dag and task information required.

*Note*: I can make the e-mail work if I dont pass in `contextdictionary` but I want to get dag ,task and other information and add some more logic for which I need the context Dictionary any advise appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your pythonOperator is missing op_kwargs with a key value related to the required positional argument, it should have something like below,

```
PythonOperator(task_id='fail_task',
                         python_callable=notify_email,
                         provide_context = True,
                         op_kwargs={'contextDict': "value"}
                         dag=dag)
```

Note: change the "value" to the relevant one.

If contextDict is not mandatory then remove it from the function and run it like how you are doing it before.